# Bash function into bashrc doesn´t be executed, receiving command not found instead

Tags: bash

Im developing a bash function that takes a number from param and repeats the last n commands of the shell using the command !-x, where x is the number of the command in reverse (last command is !-1, and the penultimate is the !-2, etc)

I'm trying this two different approaches, one by `echo` and another without it, and none works.

```
function rep()
{
        for i in $(seq 1 $1)
        do 
        "!-$i" # with echo is echo "!-$i"
        done
}
```

How can I enforce to the bash to execute the command and recognize it?

This is the exit in terminal:

```
rep 3
!-1: command not found
!-2: command not found
!-3: command not found
```

Comment: Since `!` is within quotes, the exclamation mark does not have a specific meaning, and you simply try to execute a command named i.e. `!-1`. Having said this, I don't think that you can meaningfully use history expansion (using `!`) in a function. Even if you explicitly turned it on, the most recent command would probably be the previous command in the function.

Comment: Could you recommend another approach? Something like a cat from the last x history lines maybe?

Comment: How about using the `history` command? If your function runs in an interactive bash, I think `history` should print the history. Another possibility would be to use `history -a`, which should force writing the history to the history file, and then access this file as `$HISTFILE`.